# use javax.persistence.Query in hibernate 4.2.3

Tags: hibernate, named-query

I use hibernate-4.2.3 and i will run my first `NamedQuery`. i create it as below:
`@NamedQuery(name="LoadUserWithEmail",query="select u from User u where email=:email")`
after that i get it with `session.createNamedQuery`:

```
        SessionFactory sessionFactory=SessionFactoryBuilder.build();
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        javax.persistence.Query query=  (javax.persistence.Query) session.getNamedQuery("LoadUserWithEmail");
        query.setParameter("email", email);
        User user=  (User) query.getSingleResult();
```

but when i run this code i get following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl cannot be cast to javax.persistence.Query
at ir.sarresid.persistence.dao.UserDaoImpl.getWithEmail(UserDaoImpl.java:15)
at ir.sarresid.persistence.test.PersonTest.getUser(PersonTest.java:51)
at ir.sarresid.persistence.test.PersonTest.main(PersonTest.java:17)
```

how i can solve it. i will not use org.hibernate.Query.
Do you have any solution. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing Hibernate-specific types and annotations with JPA types and annotations. SessionFactory and Session are Hibernate-specific classes, and `session.getNamedQuery()` returns an object that implements `org.hibernate.Query`, not `javax.persistence.Query`.

On the other hand, `javax.persistence.Query` is a JPA class and will be returned if you create the named query using JPA's EntityManager, e.g.:

```
javax.persistence.Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("LoadUserWithEmail");
```

Note also that there is a `org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQuery` and a `javax.persistence.NamedQuery`.

It is usually simpler to not mix the types and annotations of the two interfaces (SessionFactory vs JPA). If you use SessionFactory, you should stick with the Hibernate-specific types.